# DB2RELOCATEDB does not work as expected

Tags: database, db2, move, maximo

I'm trying to move the db2 instance from C drive to D drive following this [guide](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21321404)

However, at the step to run DB2RELOCATEDB command, it displays an error that I don't know how to solve:

```
DBT1022N  The DB2RELOCATEDB tool must be run under instance "CTGINST1".
```

I have run dbilist and see that the CTGINST1 instance is correct and in the list.

Here is the full content of my reloc.cfg file:

```
DB_NAME=MAXDB75
DB_PATH=C:\,D:\
INSTANCE=CTGINST1
NODENUM=0
STORAGE_PATH=C:\,D:\
```

Comment: What is the result of `db2 get instance`? What does the environment variable `DB2INSTANCE` contain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have installed DB2 on a Windows Server.

I logged in locally as db2admin via RDP (Remote Desktop Protocol).

> Go to Start > IBM DB2 > Command Window shortcut

Type SET which will display all your environment variables

I had to SET the DB2INSTANCE from DB2 to CTGINST1

For example, this is what you would type on the command prompt:

```
SET DB2INSTANCE=CTGINST1
```

I was in your exact position when I setting up the Administrative Workstation for our upgrade from Maximo 6.2.8 to 7.1.1.11 to 7.5.0.3

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you have two DB2 versions installed, or you have multiple db2 instances in your machine. Make sure your environment loads correctly the same instance where your database is hosted.

One way to check that the right instance profile was loaded is by executing

```
db2 list db directory
```

If you see your db as local, you are there. If it says it is a remote database, you have to change the instance.

Comment: Thank you for you insight. I just run the command and here is the result:  

C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN>db2 list db directory

 Database alias                       = MAXDB75
 Database name                        = MAXDB75
 Node name                            = TCP1BE7C
 Database release level               = d.00
 Comment                              =
 Directory entry type                 = Remote
 Catalog database partition number    = -1
 Alternate server hostname            =
 Alternate server port number         =

Comment: So it is remote now? How come since the database is installed and setup locally in the machine. 

Then what can I do to resolve this properly? All I want is to move the db from C to D drive

Comment: You have to change the instance. You can change the default instance in Windows by executing the file db2swtchg.exe (In the Start menu, something like Default DB2 and Database Client Interface Selection Wizard)

Comment: You could change the instance by set DB2INSTANCE=MYOTHERINSTANCE. However, you should know the name of the other instance. You can get all instances in one installation by db2ilist